# Can't change user to mpm-itk user

Tags: apache-2.2, users

I tried to use mpm-itk to isolate my apache virtual host using this  [tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/running-vhosts-under-separate-uids-gids-with-apache2-mpm-itk-on-debian-etch). I created user `bean` and group `bean`, I created a password for this user using `passwd bean`. When I try to swith to this user using `sudo su - bean` it doesn't change at all, how can I enable to switch to this user?

Comment: As the answer points out your new user probably doesn't have a shell. But that is in fact also unnecessary for usage in mpm-itk context.

Answer (score 0):

yua are add user as no shell

```
-s /bin/false
```

no shell = no switch

```
usermod --shell /bin/bash bean
```